# useOptimistic for create update and delete operations

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, react-hooks

With the new useOptimistic hook I wanted to use it for more then just simple setState calls and rather have it work for create, update and delete calls. While this is a new hook and there are not a lot of code out there showing use cases I wanted an opinion on if there is a better way to do it then my below code.

```js
const [optimisticTasks, setOptimisticTasks] = useOptimistic(tasks, (state, { action, task }: { action: string, task: Task }) => {
    if (action === 'delete') return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== task.id)
    if(action === 'update') return state.map(t => t.id === task.id ? task : t)
    return [...state, task]
  })
```

I apologize for this not being a 'proper' stack overflow question but I just want to get some opinions on if this is a good way to go about using this hook for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think your code is spot on. `useOptimistic` accepts a reducer as a second argument which is what you are passing it.

A common pattern is using a switch statement within a reducer, so something like this:

```
const [optimisticTasks, setOptimisticTasks] = useOptimistic(
  tasks,
  (state, { action, task }: { action: string; task: Task }) => {
    switch (action) {
      case "delete":
        return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== task.id);
      case "update":
        return state.map((t) => (t.id === task.id ? task : t));
      default:
        return [...state, task];
    }
  },
);
```

Another thing I can think of is defining the reducer as a separate function and then passing it to `useOptimistic` to improve readability, especially as it starts to grow.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this for updating lists...

I have one for updating lists and one for items.

```
export const optimisticListUpdate = (state, {type, key, body}) => {

  if(type==='set') {

    return ({ ...body })
    
  }
  else if(type==='add') {

    return ({ ...state, items: [{...body, optimistic: true}, ...state.items] })

  }
  else if(type==='delete') {
    
    let keys = Object.keys(key)
    
    let items = state.items.filter( x => {

      const isMatch = Object.entries(key).every(([key, value]) => key in x && x[key] === value);

      return !isMatch

    })

    return ({ ...state, items })
  }
  else if(type==='update') {

    let keys = Object.keys(key)

    var items = [...state.items].map( x => {
      let match = true
      keys.forEach( k => {
        if(x[k]===key[k]) match = false
      })

      if(!match) return {...x, ...body, optimistic: true}
      else return x
    })

    return ({ ...state, items })
  }

}
```